# Get client SSL handshake data using IIS

Tags: ssl, iis, handshake

When working with IIS, is it possible to get information about SSL handshake?

I want to extract all the info the client is sending in it's "[HelloMessage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security#Protocol_details)":

- highest TLS protocol version it supports
- a list of suggested cipher suites
- a list of suggested compression methods
- a list of supported application protocols(for clients who use ALPN)